# Inverted color marks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib` to draw a bar chart with many different colors. I also draw a number of markers on the plot with scatter.

Since I am already using many different colors for the bars, I do not want to use a separate contrasting color for the marks, as that would add a big limit to the color space I can choose my bars from.

Therefore, the question is whether it is possible to have scatter draw marks, not with a given color, but with a color that is the inverse of the color that happens to be behind any given mark, wherever it is placed.

Also, note that the marks may fully overlap bars, partly overlap bars, or not overlap a bar at all.

Comment: why don't you put some code example here so we could have a better starting point to help you? I would really like to, but I need to think of an example with bars and scatter together ...

Comment: Oz123, basically just create an axes and do axes.bars(<data>) and axes.scatter(<data>) there's not more imagination to it than that.

Answer (score 0):

I post here a schematic approach how to solve your problem with out any real python code, it might help though.
When  actually plotting you need to store all in some kind of two lists, which will enable you to access them later.

- For each element, bar and marker you can get the color.
- For each marker you can find if it overlapping or inside a bar, for example you could use`nxutils.pntpoly()` [point in polygon test] from matplotlib itself.
- Now you can decide on the best color. If you know the color of the bar in RGB format you can
  calculate the completing color of the marker using some simple rules you can define.
- When you got the color use the method set_color() or the appropriate method the object has.

Comment: This would become immensely complicated stupifyingly fast, might just as well build a bitmap from scratch... The problem is that the markers may even need to be multicolored if they partly overlay a bar, additionally marker size is in points while bar sizes are in axes coordinates which complicates things

Comment: Imagine that one would use scatter to put marks on an arbitrary full color image, in that case a pseudo color 'invert' would be the way to go. Basically I would want to give a function with parameter the color that happens to be in the plot for any given pixel as the color passed to scatter. Sort of like a pixel shader. Though just giving color 'invert' would of course be much simpler still, but I already gathered that that is not available

Comment: @wich, why do you start your comment with 'imagine'. This is Stackoverflow, not a science fiction forum. Post some code, so we can start from somewhere!